# Removing meta boxes: remove-meta_box() or unset()?

Tags: metabox

I've seen two ways to remove meta boxes: remove_meta_box() and unset().

```
function TEST_remove_dashboard_widgets(){
    remove_meta_box( 'dashboard_recent_comments', 'dashboard', 'normal' );
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'bmc_remove_dashboard_widgets');
```

vs.

```
function TEST_remove_dashboard_widgets() {
    global $wp_meta_boxes;
    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_recent_comments']);
}
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'bmc_remove_dashboard_widgets');
```

remove_meta_box seems better since it's clearly intended just for that, but I've also seen the unset formulation in several places.

Why would I use one vs. the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When in doubt use the API.

Let’s say the structure of `$wp_meta_boxes` will change or go away one day.

`remove_meta_box()` will still work, because the API is a contract between core and developers. Unsetting some keys in a global variable might break.

`unset()` is easier to write when you want to remove a whole group: `unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard'])` is clearly simpler than running through each separate box. But shorter code is not always better, so this should not be used in public code.

Note, both methods actually work differently: `unset()` removes an element from the array, while `remove_meta_box()` set the elements value to `FALSE`:

```
foreach ( array('high', 'core', 'default', 'low') as $priority )
    $wp_meta_boxes[$page][$context][$priority][$id] = false;
```

Other plugins might rely on the existence of that element – and break after you have used `unset()`.

Comment: Unsetting global variables seemed like a hacky approach. I'm glad to hear the clean-feeling way is also the right way.