# How to create extendable wordpress plugins

Tags: plugins, customization

I have a generic question that I would like to ask.

How do we go about creating an extendable wordpress plugin. I would like to create a plugin that I can easily allow new extensions to be hooked up to it.

Does anyone have any tips or guides or tutorials to doing this?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to create an API for my plugin?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98735/how-to-create-an-api-for-my-plugin)

Answer (score 3):

The following:

- Use hooks and filters to power things. Pass args into a filter before doing things with them, pass return values to filters before returning them, etc, hooks and filters everywhere
- namespace everything, `tomjn_twittercount` is a better function name than `twittercount`
- Practice good common sense generic programming, e.g. use dependency injection, use proper OOP ( a single class containing a bunch of functions isn't OOP )
- Document your APIs
- Use your APIs internally to build the plugin
- Document your APIs
- Did I mention documenting your APIs?

I'd suggest using PHPDoc inline documentation extensively. It'll allow you to auto-generate documentation using [PHP Documentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/)

e.g.

```
/**
 * Prints hello world
 * 
 * @access private
 * @abstract
 * @return void
 */
 private function helloworld() {
     echo 'hello world';
 }
```

Comment: You can add Document your APIs to the list :)!

Answer (score 0):

It is about creating custom hooks. The main ways is by using `apply_filters()` and `do_action()`.

More detailed explanations is here https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/creating-custom-hooks/