# Using filters and actions for plugin API?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, api, customization

I want to integrate a public API to a plugin that I develop.

The usual way other plugins integrate APIs is to define some functions that can be called by any theme or plugin.

However, I think this is a bad idea since it will cause errors when my API plugin is not active and I came up with the idea of using filters and actions for the API. Much like this:

```
// Get some user specific data from my plugin:
$data = false;
if ( apply_filters( 'mp:is-active' ) ) {
    $data = apply_filters( 'mp:get-user-data' );
}

// Add a private notification for a single user:
do_action( 'mp:send-notification', $user_id, $message );
```

The question is:

I have never seen this kind of API in other plugins yet, so is there a good reason not to use it (e.g. bad performance, etc)

Or do you think this is a good way to go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely this approach has some benefits, but has also some issues.

### It's not really easy to use

If the target of your plugin are WordPress developers, they will be very familiar with plugin API, but *end users* are not.

For a non-developer, something like:

```
$data = give_me_the_data();
```

It's easier to understand, remember and type than:

```
$data = apply_filters( 'give_me_the_data' );
```

If you look at some of the questions on this site, you can understand how much confusion there is regarding action and filters in WordPress among newbie and non developers.

### The "typo" issue

As a person that makes a lot of typos, I know that they are frustrating. If you write a function with a typo, it throws an error and the user immediately recognizes the problem. A typo in an action name will make the API fail but it's pretty hard to recognize.

As example:

```
$data = apply_filters('mp:get-user-data'); // works

$data = apply_filters('mo:get-user-data'); // does not work, hard to find why

$data = mp_get_user_data(); // works

$data = mo_get_user_data(); // does not work and throws an error, immediately found
```

### The global hell

Actions and filters are just global variables. If you use them to build your API, your code can be f***ed up by any single other line of code present in the system.

It means that a bug in any who-knows-which plugin can make your plugin fail for no apparent reason. And the reason is that is not your plugin to fail.

Example:

```
do_action( 'mp:send-notification', $user_id, $message );

// somewhere else
add_action( 'all', 'do_something_bad_that_makes_your_plugin_fail');
```

Moreover, anyone can use those hooks and even if it may bring a lot of flexibility to your API, it also introduces a lot of complexity.

For example, if you use objects as arguments, being objects passed by reference, it's possible they are modified before your callback runs.

### Conclusion

These are all the reasons that come now into my mind, but maybe there are other reasons if this approach is not widely used.

For me, I would not use this approach, especially for the last point, but I can not say it is absolutely wrong in WordPress context.

So I don't want to strongly discourage you in using it, just suggesting to consider all the issues in advance, because once you publicly release an API, it's very hard to switch.

Comment: Wow, amazing answer! Very useful information, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Both approaches are not mutually exclusive. As @gmazzap said, don’t create a callback hell.

But you can provide an initial hook, so other developers don’t have to rely on the rather slow `function_exists()` checks.

### Example

In your plugin, provide a hook that other developers can use to call your classes and functions safely.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', [new Your_Plugin_Bootstrap, 'setup' ], 0 );

class Your_Plugin_Bootstrap {

    public function setup() {

        // set up your data and the auto-loader, then:
        do_action( 'your_plugin_loaded' );
    }
}
```

Now a third-party developer can use that hook and proceed with "normal" PHP.

```
add_action( 'your_plugin_loaded', function() {

    // safely use your plugin's classes here.
});
```

We [do that in MultilingualPress](http://make.marketpress.com/multilingualpress/2014/10/a-basic-plugin-for-multilingualpress/), and the feedback from other developers was very good so far. It is easy to understand, and you have to learn just one hook.

See also: [How to create an API for my plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98783/73)